# change position in google adwords via api

Tags: google-ads-api

Is there a way to change the position preference range of a keyword using the Google Adwords API?

so, if i want to bid on a keyword only if it'll show up from 1 to 4, how would i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of this writing Google does not expose an api that would allow you to do this.